# Instagram: "invalid media id" when getting likes

Tags: instagram

GET https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/701911634259373871_563658994/likes

```
    HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
    "error_type": "APINotFoundError",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "invalid media id"
```

Media id is ok (I've got it from https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/563658994/media/recent)

Same problem for likes of other media from instagram.com/infiniti_russia

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided access_token field in the url. You need authroized token to access it.

Your link should look like this

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/563658994/media/recent?access_token={Your access token goes here}

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the media item you are trying to get the likes doesn't belong to a private user.